# "the sun is hitting my face." vs "the sunshine is touching my face"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Please advise me. If I want to say that the sunshine is coming to my face,
do I say

> the sun is hitting my face.

or

> the sunshine is touching my face.

?

I am trying to check online, but didn't find the exact way of posting this question on google!

Whats the best way to say that?

Comment: "the sunshine is touching my face" sounds dramatic.

Comment: The most natural way to express it would be "the sun is shining on my face".

Answer (score 2):

> The sunshine is **on** my face.
>   The sunshine is **hitting** my face.

would be ways to express you have sunshine directly on your face

[image]